# Error During Deploying the project on openshift

Tags: laravel-5, openshift

```
remote: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/lib:/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/libs:/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/libraries:/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/src:/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor:/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/vendors:/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/php/phplib/pear/pear/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 5707de542d52712b1100001c (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'deploy' for 5707de542d52712b1100001c application php
remote: #<IO:0x000000008043a0>
remote: #<IO:0x00000000804328>
remote: )
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `/vendor/autoload.php` is not available in your repo:

```
require(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (...) in /var/lib/openshift/5707de542d52712b1100001c/app-root/runtime/repo/bootstrap/autoload.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying an app for the first time, you need to run the `composer install` script to install the vendor packages. Do this using the commandline:

```
composer install
```

This will install the laravel framework and other dependencies use by your project.